# Characterizing units in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove a result, for which I have got one part, but I am not able to get the converse part.

**Theorem.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Then $f(X)=a_{0}+a_{1}X+a_{2}X^{2} + \cdots + a_{n}X^{n}$ is a unit in $R[X]$ if and only if $a_{0}$ is a unit in $R$ and $a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}$ are all *nilpotent* in $R$.

**Proof.** Suppose $f(X)=a_{0}+a_{1}X+\cdots +a_{n}X^{n}$ is such that $a_{0}$ is a unit in $R$ and $a_{1},a_{2}, \dots,a_{r}$ are all nilpotent in $R$. Since $R$ is commutative, we get that $a_{1}X,a_{2}X^{2},\cdots,a_{n}X^{n}$ are all nilpotent and hence also their sum is nilpotent. Let $z = \sum a_{i}X^{i}$ then $a_{0}^{-1}z$ is nilpotent and so $1+a_{0}^{-1}z$ is a unit. Thus $f(X)=a_{0}+z=a_{0} \cdot (1+a_{0}^{-1}z)$ is a unit since product of two units in $R[X]$ is a unit.

I have not been able to get the converse part and would like to see the proof for the converse part.

Comment: If $x$ is nilpotent then $1-x$ is a unit.

Comment: @Chandru1: $\ u$ unit, $z^n = 0\ \Rightarrow\ u-z\ |\ u^n - z^n = u^n,\ $ so $\ u - z\ $ is a unit, being a divisor of the unit $u^n\:.\ $ Thus $\ $ **unit + nilpotent = unit**.

Comment: The idea in the prior comment is a [special case of the **method of simpler multiples**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242)

Comment: Just a side remark over the integral domain we have $(R [x])^\times = R^\times$

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If $R$ is a domain then easily $f(X)$ a unit implies that $a_i = 0$ for $i>0$. Now $R\to R/\mathfrak p$, for $\mathfrak p$ prime, reduces to the domain case, yielding that the $a_i$, $i>0$ are in every prime ideal. But the intersection of all prime ideals is the nilradical, the set of all nilpotent elements - as you proved [a few days ago.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/x-not-nilpotent-implies-there-is-a-prime-ideal-not-containing-x)

**Remark** $ $ This is a prototypical example of [reduction to domains by factoring out prime ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120/is-1-a-prime-number/5735#5735)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3273044/242) for units in the Laurent polynomial ring $R[x,x^{-1}]\ \ $

Comment: While this is a nice quick proof, it has the disadvantage of not working in constructive mathematics (where non-trivial commutative rings may have no prime ideals). But there is a trick to make it work at least without the axiom of choice, by reducing (with standard methods) to the case of a finitely generated and hence countable commutative non-trivial ring, which always has a maximal ideal without using the (full) axiom of choice.

Answer (score 79):

Let $f=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k$ and $g= \sum_{k=0}^m b_kX^k$. If $f g=1$, then clearly $a_0,b_0$ are units and:

$$a_nb_m=0 \tag1$$
$$a_{n-1}b_m+a_nb_{m-1}=0$$

(on multiplying both sides by $a_n$)

$$\Rightarrow (a_n)^2b_{m-1}=0 \tag2$$
$$a_{n-2}b_m+a_{n-1}b_{m-1}+a_nb_{m-2}=0$$
(on multiplying both sides by $(a_n)^2$)
$$\Rightarrow (a_n)^3b_{m-2}=0 \tag3$$
$$.....$$
$$.....+a_{n-2}b_2+a_{n-1}b_1+a_nb_0=0$$
(on multiplying both sides by $(a_n)^m$)
$$\Rightarrow (a_n)^{m+1}b_{0}=0 \tag{m+1}$$

Since $b_0$ is an unit, it follows that $(a_n)^{m+1}=0$.

Hence, we proved that $a_n$ is nilpotent, but this is enough. Indeed, since $f$ is invertible, $a_nx^n$ being nilpotent implies that $f-a_nX^n$ is unit and we can repeat (or more rigorously, perform induction on $\deg(f)$).

Comment: Why does $a_{n-1}b_m+a_nb_{m-1}=0 \Rightarrow (a_n)^2b_{m-1}=0$ ?

Comment: Wait, got it, though surely that is only true if $a_n \in (Z)R$?

Comment: @Nethesis If by $Z$ you mean the center, it is probably because the ring is given commutative ;)

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I was looking for an answer about a non commutative ring and din't see that in the question, my bad @N.S.

Comment: @Nethesis No problem. I am not to familiar with polynomials in non-commutative rings, how do you define multiplication? What is $(ax) \cdot (bx^2)$?

Comment: $abx^3$, the indeterminates will still commute, the coefficients won't

Comment: @N.S. Could you explain how $a_n$ being nilpotent implies $f-a_nX^n$ is a unit

Comment: @zed111 In a commutative ring you have unit-nilpotent=unit. The proof is easy: if u is unit and v is nilpotent, then $v^n=0$ which means $$u^n=u^n-v^n=(u-v)(u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}v+...+v^{n-1})$$ This shows that $$(u-v)(u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}v+...+v^{n-1})(u^{-1})^n=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different proof.

If $f  = \sum_n a_n X^n \in R[X]$ is a unit, then also $f(0)=a_0 \in R$ is a unit. By considering $a_0^{-1} f$, we may assume $a_0 = 1$ and write $f = 1 - g$ for some $g \in \langle X \rangle$. In the ring of formal power series $R[[X]]$ every such element is invertible, namely with $(1-g)^{-1} = 1 + g + g^2 + \cdots$. In fact, this series converges since the coefficient of $X^n$ remains stable after $g^{n+1},\dotsc$, or alternatively use that $R[[X]]$ is $X$-adically complete. So now the only assumption we have is that $(1-g)^{-1} \in R[[X]]$ is actually contained in $R[X]$. This clearly implies $g^n=0$ for some $n$. Then the constant term of $g$ is nilpotent, and it follows inductively that all coefficients of $g$ are nilpotent.