# Is it correct that $f \in R[X]$ is a unit, iff $a_0$ is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be ring and $R[X]$ its polynomial ring in one indeterminate $X$. Then
$$
 f \in R[X] \mbox{ is a unit } \Leftrightarrow a_0 \mbox{ is a unit }
$$
for $f = a_0 + a_1 X + \ldots + a_n X^n$.

If $f \cdot g  = 1$ with $g = b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots b_n X^n$, then $a_0 b_0 = 1$, hence $a_0$ is a unit. Conversely, suppose $a_0$ is a unit, and choose $b_0$ such that $a_0 b_0 = 1$ and define
\begin{align*}
 b_1 & := b_0(-a_1 b_0) \\ 
 b_2 & := b_0(-a_2 b_0 - a_1 b_1 ) \\
 b_3 & := b_0(-a_3 b_0 - a_2 b_1 - a_1 b_2 ) \\
 \vdots \\
 b_n & := b_0(-a_n b_0 - a_{n-1} b_1 - \ldots - a_1 b_{n-1} ).
\end{align*}
Then every sum of the form
$$
 \sum_{i + j = k} a_i b_j
$$
for $k > 0$ vanishes, hence the polynomial $g = b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots + b_n X^n$ is an inverse for $f$.

I am just asking if this is correct, or if I have overlooked something. I am asking because I nowhere find this  characterisation stated for general rings (just find a variant for fields), and for rings I just find the result:
$$
 f \in R[X] \mbox{ is a unit } \Leftrightarrow
 a_0 \mbox{ is a unit and } a_1, \ldots, a_n \mbox{ are nilpotent }
$$
which proofs could be found on this page, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380559/prove-that-a-0-is-a-unit-and-that-a-1-a-2-a-n-are-nilpotents-in-r), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606726/nilpotent-invertible-polynomial-over-commutative-ring) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/characterizing-units-in-polynomial-rings). But nowhere do I find it that the condition of nilpotency could be dropped in the implication from right to left.

Comment: What happens in your argument if say $f(x)=1+x$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: If $R$ has no zero divisors, then $\deg (f\cdot g) = \deg f + \deg g$, so only constants can be units.

Comment: What is the case that over a commutative ring $R$, $f=a_0+a_1x+\cdots\in R[[x]]$ is a unit in $R[[x]]$ iff $a_0$ is a unit in $R$, where $R[[x]]$ is the formal power series ring.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I hope I have interpreted them correctly and compiled and answer.

Comment: Your result as stated is false. However, it's true in the ring $R[[x]]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just considered the coefficients in the result $f\cdot g$ that have a term of the form $a_0 b_j$ $j=1,\ldots,n$ in them, and those will vanish. But I totally forgot about the other coefficients like $a_1 b_n + \ldots + a_n b_1$ and so on up $i + j = n + n$ with $g = b_0 + b_1 X + \ldots b_n X$, $f = a_0 + a_1 X + \ldots a_n X$.

Thanks to @charmichael561 and @DanielFischer for their comments!

But if we contine this process indefinitely, we can build a series $g \in R[[x]]$ and for this $f\cdot g = 1$ if I interpret @LordSharkTheUnknown's comment correctly. But we can find no polynom.