# Example that $u$ irreducible in commutative ring $R$ with $1_R$ but reducible in polynomial ring $R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is domain and $u$ is irreducible in $R$, it is true that $u$ is always irreducible in $R[x]$.

However, this is not true if $R$ is not domain.

I tried this in $ R=\Bbb Z_n$ , when $n$ is not prime, but $\Bbb Z_n$ is also not proper example.

How can I find this example?

Definition of irreducible in a commutative ring $R$ with $1$:

$u$ is an irreducible of $R$ iff u is non-zero, non-unit, and $u=ab$ imply $a$ or $b$ is a unit of $R$.

Comment: I made some edits, but I've tried to preserve the original question. Please ensure the current question reflects the same question and content contained in it prior to editing.

Comment: definition of irreducible can be defined in commutative ring with unity.

Comment: $u$ is irreducible of $R $  iff  $ u=ab$ imply $a $ or $ b $ unit of $R$

Comment: [Classification of invertible polynomials in $R[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30390) can come in handy.

Comment: Usually, $u$ being a unit is excluded to be irreducible. In your definition it is possible. Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878029/verify-that-if-u-is-irreducible-in-z-n-then-u-is-irreducible-in-z-nx) for $R=\Bbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: @Kolja  yes , it is true that in commutative ring with unity, $f$ is unit iff constant coefficient is unit and the others coefficient is nilpotent.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde   it's my mistake , thanks