# Find units in $\mathbb Z_4[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the units in $\mathbb Z_4[x]$.

I saw something online about this possibly having an infinite amount of units, but am not sure.

Any help someone can give would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466434/find-a-polynomial-of-degree-0-in-z-4x-that-is-a-unit?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The units in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are exactly those numbers that are relatively prime to $n$. This is because if a number is relatively prime to $n$, then the number will have

$$
\gcd(k, n) = 1
$$

Hence

$$
\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_4 \ \text{such that}\\
k \times a + n \times b = 1 \\
$$

Therefore

$$
k \times a + 0 = 1\mod n \\
\text{where} \ \ k,  a \in \mathbb{Z}_4
$$

So, such a number will always have units.

The numers that are relatively primt to $4$ are $\{1, 3\}$. So, there are $2$ numbers that are units to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: I think the question is asking for the units in the {\it polynomial} ring ${\mathbb {Z}}_{4}}[x]$. Your answer doesn't quite make it I am afraid. The question is answered elsewhere on this website.