# Show that in Z/2Z[x] two polynomials are associates if and only if they are equal.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I believe that I should show the forward direction by first showing the factorization of two polynomials, f and g, such that f=p1 . . . ps and g=q1 . . . qs, where each pi and qj are irreducible polynomials. And I also know that the coefficients can only be 0 or 1 in Z/2Z. I am not sure where I should go from here to show that each of the pi=qj.

Comment: Does associate just mean differ by multiplication by a unit?  If so, just think about what the units are in Z/2Z[x]

Comment: Okay, then the only unit in Z/2Z is 1, therefore, for the polynomials to be associates that means that one is just a multiple of the other by 1 and therefore, is the same polynomial.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,1\,$ is the only unit in the domain $\,D\,$ then it is the only unit in $\,D[x]\,$ since [both domains have the same units.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/736273/242) More generally [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19145/242) on the units of $\,R[x].$