# Two questions regarding polynomial rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Give an example of a natural number $n > 1$ and a polynomial $f(x) ∈ \Bbb Z_n[x]$ of degree $> 0$ that is a unit in $\Bbb Z_n[x]$.

For this is set $n=2$. So then $f(x) = x \in \Bbb Z_2[x] $. This is a unit because $f(1)f^{-1}(1) = 1$. I don't think this is correct as I can't use $f(0)$.

Find all the polynomials of degree less or equal to $2$ in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$.

I don't really know how to do this. I thought that since we are working in $\Bbb Z_2$,I can't really have a polynomial of degree $2$. This is confusing me But if I have to: $ax^2, ax^2 + bx, ax^2 + bx + c, ax^2 + c, bx, bx + c, c: a,b,c \in \Bbb Z_2$

Comment: If the question had not said less than or equal to $2$, is the maximal degree the polynomial can have $1$? @SeanI

Comment: degree of the polynomial is irrelevant to the characteristic of the ring. It will be relevant if you evaluate at a point. I think this is what confused you. Your list seems to be correct. But I think the question wants you to explicitly list the polynomials. For the first part this might help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/characterizing-units-in-polynomial-rings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $x$ is not a unit; there is no polynomial $p(x)$ such that $xp(x)=1$. This is because $\deg xp(x)=1+\deg p(x)\ge 1$.

Actually, one shows that, for a polynomial of positive degree to be a units, it is necessary that its leading coefficient to be a zero-divisor, which implies $n$ to be *composite*. A simple example: in $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z[x]$, we have:
$$(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1=1.$$

As to the polynomials of degree at most $2$ in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[x]$ you just have to write out all possible sets of coefficients:
$$\{0,1, x,1+x, x^2, 1+x^2, x+x^2, 1+x+x^2\}.$$

Comment: I gave one such example.

Comment: Sorry. I just read back through that. So how is $2x+1$ a zero divisor? What is its inverse in $\Bbb Z_4$? And why does it imply that n has to be composite?

Comment: $2x+1$ is not a zero-divisor. It can't be, since it is a unit, and its inverse is itself. What I said is the *leading coefficient* has to be a zero-divisor. Indeed, mod$4$, $2$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So why would the leading coefficient have to be a zero divisor? Is there some theorem that states that?

Comment: Because if it isn't, the degree of the product will be the sum of the degrees of the factors, hence it can't be $0$, the degree of the constant $1$.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll remove my comments about this point. They have no interest for someone else.