# Rings constructed from commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and define $$B = \{ f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n X^n: a_n \in R\}$$ where $X$ is an indeterminate over $R$.

a. Show that $B$ is a ring.

b. Prove or disprove: $f$ is a unit if and only if $a_0$ is a unit.

I could not relate this question with the post [Characterizing units in polynomial rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/characterizing-units-in-polynomial-rings) exactly since there is nothing about nilpotent elements. Maybe I need a more detailed explanation.

Comment: What you have tried? Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: The basic way to compute the inverse here is to use the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{a+z}$ centered at $z=0$.

Comment: It is OK for b but how will we prove that B is a ring?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$\rightarrow$ is easy. To prove $\leftarrow$, you may suppose $a_0=1$.

Just write the (infinite) system of equations for the coefficients of $c_0+c_1 X+\dots+c_nX^n+\dotsm $ to be an inverse of $f$:
\begin{align}
c_0&=1, &c_0a_1+c_1&=0,& &c_0a_2+c_1a_1+c_2=0,\\
\dots&\dots\dots\dots&&&& c_0a_n+c_1a_{n-1}+\dots+c_{n-1}a_1+c_n=0,\\
\dots&\dots\dots\dots
 \end{align}
We thus have a recursive definition of the coefficients:
$$c_0=1,\quad c_n=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_ka_{n-k}.$$