# How to show $u \in R^{x} \implies u \in R[X]^{x}$ for integral domain $(R,+, \times)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I am studying ring theory and have come across polynomial rings. There is an exercise to show that $$u \in R^{x} \implies u \in R[X]^{x}$$ where $(R,+, \times)$ is an integral domain.

I know that $R^{x}$ is the set of all units in R, which is the set of all elements of $R$ with a multiplicative inverse, and similarly for $R[X]^{x}$. But I am stuck with proving the above statement.

Comment: You should look at how $R$ embeds in $R[X]$. This will provide multiplicative inverses for $u$ in $R[X]$.

Comment: There are several duplicates, e.g., also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211152/how-do-i-show-that-the-units-of-rx-the-units-of-r-where-r-is-an-integ).