# For a field $F$, what are the elements of $U(F[x])$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, euclidean-domain

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain. An element $u \in R$ is said to be a unit if there is a $v \in R$ such that $uv = 1$. The set of units in $R$ is denoted by $U(R)$.

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring. We say that an element $u \in R$ is a unit if $u$ has a multiplicative inverse. Prove that the set $U (R) = \{u \ R \colon \; $u$  \text{ is a unit}  \}$ is a group under multiplication.

Certainly $1$ is a unit in $R$, so $U(R)$ contains an identity element. Associativity and commutativity of multiplication is inherited from $R$. Let $u \ U(R)$. Then there is $u′ \in R$ such that $uu′ = 1$. Hence $u′$ is a unit, so $u′ \in U(R)$ and $U(R)$ is closed under inverses. Now let $u,v \in  U(R)$. Therefore there are $u′,v′ \in R$ such that $uu′ = 1$ and $vv′ = 1$. Since $uvu′v′ = 1$, it follows that uv is a unit in $R$, so $U(R)$ is closed under multiplication. Hence $U(R)$ is a group.

After proving all of this then my question is: Let $F$ be a field. What are the elements of $U(F[x])$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions asks you for which polynomial $p(x)$ you can find another polynomial $q(x)$ such that their product is $1$.

Certainly neither $p$ nor $q$ can be $0$.

Now, consider what $pq= 1$  says about the degree of the polynomial $p$.

A moments thought will reveal that $p$ has to have degree $0$, that it is a constant polynomial.

So, $U(F[X])$ is a subset of the non-zero constant polynomials, that is, $F \setminus \{0\}$.

It remains to consider which elements of $F \setminus \{0\}$  indeed has a multiplicative inverse. Since $F$ is a field it follows readily that each element of $F \setminus \{0\}$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Thus, $U(F[X]) = F \setminus \{0\}$.

This argument readily generalizes to show that for $R$ an integral domain
$U(R[X]) = U(R)$. Note that one uses that $R$ is an integral domain when concluding from $pq=1$ that $p$, $q$ are constant.

For a more general result see [Characterizing units in polynomial rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/characterizing-units-in-polynomial-rings)

Comment: Thank you. I was over complicating things and thinking that it was too trivial.

Comment: You are welcome. Chances are the question is already answered somewhere on the site.

Answer (score 1):

We claim that
$$U(F[x])=U(F)=F-\{0\}.$$
Of course, $U(F) \subseteq U(F[x])$. Conversely, if $p(x) \in U(F[x])$, then by definition there exists $q(x) \in F[x]$ such that
$$p(x)q(x)=1.$$
In particular:
$$\deg(p(x)q(x))=\deg(1)$$
$$\deg(p(x))+\deg(q(x))=0,$$
which forces $\deg(p(x))=\deg(q(x))=0$. Hence, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are constant polynomials; i.e, $p=p(x),q=q(x) \in F \subset F[x]$. Since $pq=1$, it follows that $p \in U(F)$.

**Remark.** Observe that the same argument shows that if $R$ is an integral domain, then
$$U(R[x])=U(R).$$

Comment: It seems I arrived late ;)