# Counterexample to claim that Jacobson radical of a commutative ring is given by checking against units

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $J(R)$ its Jacobson radical. It is easy to check that $J(R)$ consists of exactly those $f$ for which $1 + gf \in R^\times$ for all $g$.

Let $J'(R)$ be those $f$ for which $1 + uf \in R^\times$ for all units $u$. We might conjecture that in general $J(R) = J'(R)$. I assume this is false, since I can't find it anywhere, but I've been unable to come up with a counterexample - what are some counterexamples? Is there a nice characterization of when $J(R) = J'(R)$ holds?

Answer (score 4):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.  Then $p\in J'(R)$, since the units are just the constants that are not divisible by $p$, but $p\not\in J(R)$ since $1+px$ is not a unit.

More generally, if $S$ is any ring whose Jacobson radical is not equal to its nilradical, then you could take $R=S[x]$.  Then for any $p\in S$ that is in the Jacobson radical but not the nilradical, $p\in J'(R)$ (because [every unit of $R$ is a unit of $S$ plus a nilpotent element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/characterizing-units-in-polynomial-rings)) but $p\not\in J(R)$ since $1+px$ is not a unit.