# Polynomial with co-efficient in reduced ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a reduced ring.

What can we say about $R[x]$?

Suppose $R$ is integral domain, so is $R[x]$, can we say something similar here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly $R[x]$ is reduced as well, and we can further say that $R[x]$ [has no units of positive degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/characterizing-units-in-polynomial-rings).