# Show that $f (x) = ax + 1 \in R[x]$ is invertible in $R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Consider $a ∈ R$ such that $a^2 = 0$. Show that $f (x) = ax + 1 \in  R[x]$ is invertible in $R[x]$.

I have no idea how to do it, can you give me any tips?

Comment: Hint:the sum of a nilpotent and unit is invertible by the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19145/242) for a charaxcterization of units (invertibles) in polynomial rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(ax+1)(1-ax) = 1-a^2x^2  = 1$.