# Showing the set of zero-divisors is a union of prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm working on an exercise from Atiyah and MacDonald's *Commutative Algebra*, and have hit a bump on Exercise 14 of Chapter 1.

> In a ring $A$, let $\Sigma$ be the set of all ideals in which every element is a zero-divisor. Show that set $\Sigma$ has maximal elements and that every maximal element of $\Sigma$ is a prime ideal. Hence the set of zero-divisors in $A$ is a union of prime ideals.

I see by an application of Zorn's Lemma that $\Sigma$ has maximal elements. I take $\mathfrak{m}$ to be maximal in $\Sigma$, with $xy\in\mathfrak{m}$. Since $xy$ is a zero divisor, $xyz=0$ for some $z\neq 0$. If $yz=0$, then $y$ is a zero divisor, otherwise $x$ is a zero divisor. So I guess I then want to show $x\in\Sigma$ or $y\in\Sigma$. If neither is, then $\mathfrak{m}$ is properly contained in both $(\mathfrak{m},x)$ and $(\mathfrak{m},y)$. However, I'm not sure how to show either of these ideals is again in $\Sigma$.

If my understanding is correct, elements of $(\mathfrak{m},x)$ are finite sums of the form $\sum_ia_im_i+bx$ for $a_i\in A$, $m_i\in\mathfrak{m}$ and $b\in A$. To show this sum is a zero divisor, my hunch is that if $c_im_i=0$ for $c_i\neq 0$ and $dx=0$ for $d\neq 0$, then 
$$
\left(\sum_ia_im_i+bx\right)(d\prod_ic_i)=0.
$$
My concern is that perhaps $d\prod_ic_i=0$, so the above wouldn't show that $(\mathfrak{m},x)$ consists of only zero divisors. How can I get around this? Or is there perhaps a better approach? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the "Hence" in the problem statement requires not just that $\Sigma$ has maximal elements, but that every ideal in $\Sigma$ is contained in a maximal ideal in $\Sigma$. (Your application of Zorn proves this stronger thing.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Let $\frak{m}$ be a maximal element in $\Sigma$. We want to show it is prime, i.e. that if $x\notin\frak{m}$ and $y\notin\frak{m}$, then $xy\notin\frak{m}$.

If $x\notin\frak{m}$ and $y\notin\frak{m}$, then ${\frak{m}}+(x)$ and ${\frak{m}}+(y)$ are both ideals of $A$ that strictly contain $\frak{m}$, and therefore each must contain non-zero-divisors ($\frak{m}$ is maximal among ideals consisting only of zero-divisors, so any ideal strictly containing $\frak{m}$ cannot consist only of zero-divisors). Thus the ideal $({\frak{m}}+(x))({\frak{m}}+(y))\subseteq{\frak{m}}+(xy)$ contains non-zero-divisors (because there is at least one non-zero-divisor in each of ${\frak{m}}+(x)$ and ${\frak{m}}+(y)$, and the product of two non-zero-divisors is a non-zero-divisor). But the fact that ${\frak{m}}+(xy)$ contains non-zero-divisors implies that ${\frak{m}}+(xy)$ strictly contains $\frak{m}$, hence $xy\notin\frak{m}$. Thus $\frak{m}$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you Zev, this was nice and clear.

Comment: @yunone: No problem! This is a classic method of proving that ideals that are maximal with respect to having some property are prime. In fact there are general theorems about what properties such an argument can be made about, see [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~m1reyes/ams-oka2.pdf) for example.

Comment: How one can conclude that the set of zero divisors is an union of prime ideals?

Comment: @ZevChonoles : How does one conclude that the set of zero divisors is a union of prime ideals?

Comment: @SaunDev: Read the original question by "yunone", and then read my answer.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles I think one has to modify the set $\Sigma$ to the set of all ideals containing $(x)$ (where $x$ is a zero divisor) in which every element is a zero divisor to prove that the set of all zero divisors is a union of prime ideals. What do you think?

Comment: @ZevChonoles the set of all zero divisors of $A$ will be the union of all the maximal elements of $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 14):

**Hint** $ $ The non-zero-divisors form a saturated monoid $\rm\:M\:$ (i.e. $\rm\:ab\in M\!\iff\! a\in M\:$ & $\rm\:b\in M$) so its complement is a union of prime ideals (this can be proved either by [localization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/x-not-nilpotent-implies-there-is-a-prime-ideal-not-containing-x/18205#18205), or by a direct [elementary proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25739/maximal-multiplicative-set-implies-complement-is-a-prime-ideal/25740#25740) using that an ideal maximal wrt the exclusion of a monoid is prime). For a nice exposition see the first few pages of Kaplansky: *Commutative Rings*.

**Note** $ $ For generalizations, see Lam and Reyes: [Oka and Ako Ideal Families in Commutative Rings](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/229c/7976b39de66f72c63ce3fd445f49d22eb13d.pdf) mentioned by Zev, and the paper reviewed below.

---

MR 95i:13023  13G05 06F20
Anderson, D. D.; Zafrullah, Muhammad
On a theorem of Kaplansky.
Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. A (7) 8 (1994), no. 3, 397--402.

The complement of a saturated multiplicatively closed set is a union of prime
ideals (Bourbaki). $\ $ The authors apply this fact to a property (*) of non-zero
elements in an integral domain such that the elements satisfying (*) form
a saturated multiplicatively closed set. Suitable choices of (*) yield
characterizations of UFDs [I. Kaplansky, Commutative rings, Univ. Chicago
Press, Chicago, IL, 1974; MR 49 #10674], GCD domains, valuation and Prüfer
domains. Lattice ordered groups and Riesz groups are characterized similarly. [Reviewed by C. P. L. Rhodes]

---

Zbl 816.13001

Analyzing the proof of Kaplansky's theorem, that an integral domain is a
unique factorization domain if and only if every nonzero prime ideal contains
a nonzero principal prime ideal, the authors state - leaving the proof to the
reader:

Let D be an integral domain. Let (*) be a property of elements in D.
Assume that the set S of nonzero elements in D with (*) is a nonempty
saturated multiplicatively closed set. Then every nonzero element in D has
(*) if and only if every nonzero prime ideal contains a nonzero element with
(*). This observation is then applied to various situations, to characterize

1. integral domains that are UFD's,
2. integral domains that are valuation domains,
3. integral domains that are Pruefer domains,
4. directed partially ordered groups that are lattice-ordered,
5. directed partially ordered groups that are Riesz groups.

[ K.Roggenkamp (Stuttgart)]

Answer (score 11):

The following steps lead to a solution:

(1) If $a\in\Sigma$ is not a prime ideal, we will show that $a$ is not a maximal element of $\Sigma$. Since $a$ is not a prime ideal, there exists $x,y\not\in a$ such that $xy\in a$. The ideal $(a:x)=\{z\in A:xz\in a\}$ can be considered.

(2) Prove that $a\subseteq (a:x)$ and that this inclusion is proper.

(3) Prove that $(a:x)$ consists entirely of zero-divisors. (Hint: If not, then there exists $z\in (a:x)$ such that $z$ is not a zero divisor. Deduce that $(a:z)\in \Sigma$.)

(4) Show that $a$ is not maximal. (Hint: The inclusion $a\subseteq (a:z)$ is proper. Why?)

Comment: Very nice, I'd not seen this approach before.

Comment: Thanks Amitesh for the walkthrough. So for (2), $y\in (a:x)-a$, so the inclusion is proper. For (3), taking $b\in (a:z)$, then $bzc=0$ for $c\neq 0$. But $zc\neq 0$ since $z$ is not a zero divisor, so $b$ is a zero-divisor, so $(a:z)\in\Sigma$. Finally for (4), $zx\in a$ from (2) so $x\in (a:z)-a$, and the inclusion is proper. So either way $a$ is contained in either $(a:x)$ or $(a:z)$, contradicting maximality. So $a$ must be prime.

Comment: How one can conclude that the set of zero divisors is an union of prime ideals?

Comment: @Epsilondelta If we take any zero divisor, the ideal generated by it consists entirely of zero divisors, and is therefore contained in some ideal which is maximal in the given family of ideals. This maximal ideal is therefore prime and therefore the original zero divisor is contained in a prime ideal. If we take the union over all these prime ideals, we have covered all the zero divisors but only the zero divisors. Therefore if we take the union over all these prime ideals we get exactly the set of zero divisors.

Answer (score 9):

An elements of $(\mathfrak{m},x)$ can be described as $m_1+a_1 x$ where $m_1 \in \mathfrak{m}$ and $a_1 \in A$, a little simpler than yours. And I think it is better to assume that $x \notin \mathfrak{m}, y \notin \mathfrak{m} $ then deduce a contradiction, since $(\mathfrak{m},x)$ alone may properly contain $\mathfrak{m}$, but both $(\mathfrak{m},x) \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}$, $(\mathfrak{m},y) \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}$ makes a contradiction.

So assume that $xy \in \mathfrak{m}$ with $(\mathfrak{m},x) \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}$, $(\mathfrak{m},y) \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}$, then there are $m_1+a_1 x \in (\mathfrak{m},x)$ and $m_2+a_2 y \in (\mathfrak{m},y)$ which are not 0-divisors. Then $(m_1+a_1 x)(m_2+a_2 y) \in \mathfrak{m}$ since $xy$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$. But this is a contradiction, since a product of non 0-divisors is not a 0-divisor.

Comment: Good answer! I suppose it is the same as Zev's answer; instead of considering a product of ideals, you have considered a product of elements. However, sometimes this can be more conceptual.

Answer (score 5):

Zev's answer is excellent. However, here are some exercises that provide practice with the technique Zev introduced (all rings are commutative and have a multiplicative identity):

Exercise 1: Let $A$ be a ring with at least one non-principal ideal. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all ideals of $A$ that are not principal. Prove that $\Sigma$ has maximal elements and that maximal elements of $\Sigma$ are prime. (Hint: study my answer carefully.)

Exercise 2: Let $A$ be a ring with at least one non-finitely generated ideal. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all ideals of $A$ that are not finitely generated. Prove that $\Sigma$ has maximal elements and that maximal elements of $\Sigma$ are prime. (Hint: let $I$ be a maximal element of $\Sigma$. If $I$ is not prime, then there exists $x,y\not\in I$ such that $xy\in I$. Use the fact that $I+(x)$ is finitely generated and that $(I:x)$ is finitely generated. Why are these ideals finitely generated?)

Exercise 3: Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ such that $0\not\in S$. (Definition: $S$ is closed under multiplication and $1\in S$.) Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all ideals $I$ such that $I\cap S = \emptyset$. Note that $\Sigma\neq \emptyset$ since $0\in \Sigma$. Prove that $\Sigma$ has maximal elements and that a maximal element $I$ of $\Sigma$ is a prime ideal. (Hint: use the technique Zev introduced.)

Comment: Hi! These exercises are very nice, and... maybe you'd like to tell us where are them from?