# Prove that a UFD $R$ is a PID if every nonzero prime ideal in $R$ is maximal.

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a UFD. Prove that $R$ is a PID if every nonzero prime ideal in $R$ is maximal.

The author gives the following hint: assume that every nonzero prime ideal of $R$ is maximal, and prove that every maximal ideal in $R$ is principal; then use Proposition 3.5 to relate arbitrary ideals to maximal ones, and prove that every ideal of $R$ is principal

> Proposition 3.5. Let $I ≠( 1 )$ be a proper ideal of a commutative ring $R$. Then there exists a maximal ideal $\frak{m}$ of $R$ containing $I$.

I could prove every maximal ideals is principal, but then I got stuck.
I know the question has been asked in MSE, but I couldn't find an answer that use the same method as the hint, so I really want to know how to use the method

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the book in question is Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter $\mathit0$*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already proved that every maximal ideal is principal.

Now take any proper ideal $I=(f_1, \dotsc, f_s) \subset R$ and let $I \subset (m)$ be a maximal ideal containing it.

In particular, for any $x \in I$, we have that $x$ admits the factor $m$. Thus you can consider the ideal $J=\left(\frac{f_1}{m}, \dotsc, \frac{f_s}{m} \right) \supset I$. It is easy to show that the $J$ is strictly larger than $I$, because we have $I=mJ$.

Hence by noetherian induction, we can assume that $J$ is principal, say $J=(f)$. Then $I=mJ=(mf)$.

---

Of course you need the noetherian property, but it is [well known that one can test all ideals being finitely generated on prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146884/an-ideal-that-is-maximal-among-non-finitely-generated-ideals-is-prime). And you have already checked this.

---

Ok, here is an argument without using the noetherian property, but only the ACCP property, which is a gimme for UFD's.

After having constructed $J=J_0$ with $I=m_0J_0$ (You can do this without assuming that $I$ is finitely generated), we have two cases:

1. $J_0=R$. Then $I=(m_0)$ and you are done.
2. $J_0$ is a proper ideal. Then we can repeat the argument and find $m_1$ with $J_0=m_1J_1$. Iterating this gives you $I=m_0m_1 \dotsb m_tJ_t$. Since $R$ is a UFD, this will eventually stop, since a non-zero element in $I$ has only finitely many irreducible factors. When this stops after $d$ steps, we have $J_d=R$ and thus $I=(m_0m_1 \dotsb m_d)$.