# Proving that maximally non-finitely generated ideals of a commutative ring are prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is the problem I wish to discuss: [An ideal that is maximal among non-finitely generated ideals is prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146884/an-ideal-that-is-maximal-among-non-finitely-generated-ideals-is-prime)

The strategy seems to be to assume that there exists some maximally non-f.g. ideal that is not prime, and then reach a contradiction.

At no point in the given solutions do the authors consider the possibility that the maximally non-f.g. ideal in question could be equal to the whole ring. The accepted answer starts "suppose $U$ is not prime, then $\exists x, y \in R: xy \in U, x \notin U$, $ y\notin U$". This ignores the other possibility that $U = R$.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me? I am having trouble following several similar proofs. Thanks.

Comment: If $R$ is a unital ring, then $R$ is a finitely-generated $R$-module.

Comment: Thank you. Seems this was so obvious it didn't need to be mentioned!