# Any deeper "duality" between non-zero-divisors and units of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

I'm reading Aluffi's algebra book at the moment -- specifically, I'm on the introductory rings/modules chapter.

I noticed two interesting pieces of information: in a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$,

- $x\mapsto ux$ is injective for $u$ a left non-zero-divisor
- $x\mapsto ux$ is surjective for $u$ a left unit

Is there any deeper (read: probably categorical) reason for this apparent "duality"?

Edit: Specifically, since we know that injectivity and surjectivity (well, mono- and epi-ness, but we're in $\sf Set$) are "dual", is there also some duality between the properties of being a left (resp. right) non-zero-divisor and being a left (resp. right) unit?

Comment: For a left unit, it is *also* injective. There is no duality here – just the fact that bijective implies injective.

Comment: Bernard, Najib: Please recall that $R$ is not assumed to be commutative, and be careful as for the "left"s here.

Comment: @Soham: The answer to your question is probably "no". These are absolutely trivial reformulations of the definitions. It would be better to narrow your question to get some interesting answers.

Comment: so $u$ a left unit implies $x\mapsto xu$ is injective? Since left units are right non-zero divisors.

Comment: On the other hand $u$ not a left-zero divisor does not imply $x\mapsto xu$ is surjective. Duality seems to not be dual, checkmate.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I've edited it. Does the question make a little more sense now?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I doubt that there is an honest duality between left regular elements and left units.

Comment: Dear @SohamChowdhury Do you have no interest in the observation that $x\mapsto ux$ is injective if $u$ is a right unit? (Of course, right units are left-non-zero divisors.) That seemed like the more obvious counterpart, but of course you may have already discarded it. In any case, these ideas about one-sided invertibility or cancelability are interesting. You might want to lookup Hopfian/coHopfian objects. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb, I'll definitely look those up. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that the zero divisors are [union of minimal primes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44481), while $R^{\times}$ is the intersection of $R \setminus m$ where $m$ goes through the maximal ideals of $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something which comes to my mind. I don't know if it answers the question properly.

Recall that a monoid (resp. a ring) is the "same" as a category (resp. linear category) with one object. The composition of morphisms is just the multiplication of monoid (resp. ring) elements. The notions of left units ( := *right* invertible element, what I suspect from the question) and left regular elements ( := left cancellable elements) generalize to arbitrary categories:

A morphism $f : X \to Y$ is left invertible, or more commonly, a **split monomorphism**, if there is a morphism $g : Y \to X$ such that $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_X$. A morphism is called left cancellable, or more commonly, an **epimorphism**, if for all morphisms $g,h : Z \to X$ with $f \circ g = f \circ h$ we have $g=h$. The dual notions are **split epimorphism** and **monomorphism**. Then, we have the following:

- $f$ is a split monomorphism if and only if $\hom(Y,Z) \to \hom(X,Z),~ g \mapsto g \circ f$ is surjective for all objects $Z$.
- $f$ is a split epimorphism if and only if $\hom(Z,X) \to \hom(Z,Y),~ g \mapsto f \circ g$ is surjective for all objects $Z$.
- $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $\hom(Z,X) \to \hom(Z,Y),~ g \mapsto f \circ g$ is injective for all objects $Z$.
- $f$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\hom(Y,Z) \to \hom(X,Z),~ g \mapsto g \circ f$ is injective for all objects $Z$.
- Every split monomorphism is a monomorphism.
- Every split epimorphism is an epimorphism.

From here it becomes clear that monomorphisms  and split epimorphisms (similarly, epimorphisms and split monomorphisms) have dual characterizations in terms of $\hom(Z,-)$ (resp. $\hom(-,Z)$). But I doubt that this means that the notions are dual to each other.